# After I Stringify a DE using DataExtension.Init how can I output or filter the data in JS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am wondering how can I filter data using JavaScript?

For example, I would like to output data in JS.

```
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var layouts = DataExtension.Init("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME").Rows.Retrieve();
Write(Stringify(layouts));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also loop access that data through a loop. So if your DE has a field called Email, this should pull that value

```
        for (var i = 0; i < deLength; i++) {
           var layout = layouts[i]['Email'];
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data extension rows server side prior to the `Write` function using

```
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var layouts = DataExtension.Init("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME").Rows.Retrieve({Property:"SomeFieldName",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"SomeValue"});
Write(Stringify(layouts));
```

If you are wanting to use the results on the client side you would need to do something like this:

```
//server side
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");
    var layouts = DataExtension.Init("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME").Rows.Retrieve({Property:"SomeFieldName",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"SomeValue"});
    var layouts = Stringify(layouts);
</script>

//client side
<script>
    var layouts = <ctrl:var name=layouts />
</script>
```

This should now allow you to work with the layouts variable client-side as JSON.